If there has ever been a person who has been/was... it is...?

Choosing to ditch the dye was the best decision I’ve made in a long time! I’m 58 years old. I grew up in my grandmother’s “beauty shop”. That’s what we called it back then. My grandmother, my mother and my cousin were all “beauticians”. I grew up, believing I was too old for long hair by the time I was 25 and that letting any gray hair show, would instantly age you! It was hideous and only OLD people were gray. How silly! Finally, I began to challenge those thoughts. My daughter was encouraging me to grow my short hair out and around the same time, I was seeing beautiful, younger women in my Instagram feed who were embracing their natural hair. I began to see, it’s not the color of your hair it’s the style, and how you wear it!
[...]
It has truly been a journey of self acceptance. If there has ever
been anyone who was their own, worst critic, it’s me. It’s
an ongoing journey but I can truly say, I’ve come along way!

Source: instagram.com

If there has ever been a man who has been faced with challenges of opposition both at home and away, then it is King David. First of all his father completely forgot about him when a prophet came calling at their house and enquired of him. Later he was asked to go home and tend to sheep by his brothers when he went to visit them on a battlefield. Then he had to kill a giant to prove he was not a dog like he was referred to. He later had to flee his home because his father in-law, King Saul wanted to kill him.There are people like that in the world of work too. [...]

Source: hrfocusuniverse.com
What is the distinction here between the present perfect and the past simple regarding the meaning of these sentences?
Could someone explain to me, it the author of the first example had chosen 'who has been' instead of 'who was' and the author of the second example had written 'who was' instead of  'who has been', what difference would it make?

I have not read your question. I suggest you simplify it. And real speech can be confusing.

I've read your question, and if I were you I would select two examples. It will be difficult or time consuming for any user to talk in any detail about all seven.

If there has ever been a great writer, it is Charles Dickens. I am stating that, in my opinion, he is (now, in the present) very prominent indeed in that category (great writers) even though he died in 1870.

@MichaelHarvey I understand, but my examples are a little bit different. If there has ever been a great writer, who has written/wrote some of the greatest novels in the world, it is Charles Dickens. This is the thing that I'm struggling with! Which one is correct or both are correct depending on context?

@MichaelHarvey If you take a close look at the second example in the OP, you'll notice that it's about King David who lived about 4000 years ago, and the author said: "If there has ever been a man who has been faced with..., it is King David." I don't see how does it fit in what you said: "...in British English, only the present perfect tense is used in situations where an action that occurred in the recent past that has some effect on the present,..."? Could you explain this to me?

Are we sure this isn't merely an instance of the fact that in British English, only the present perfect tense is used in situations where an action that occurred in the past that has some effect on the present, while in American English, however, it is more common to use the simple past in these cases?

@MickeyQ - OK. Good catch. Strike out 'recent'.

When it comes to choice of tenses in English, there will be some principles to follow, and some options which are better or worse. But a very important issue is to ask a simple question: What do I want to say, and which tense expresses that message? It's not just about right and wrong, it's also about meaning.
To illustrate, let's look at your first example:

It has truly been a journey of self acceptance. If there has ever been anyone who was their own, worst critic, it’s me. It’s an ongoing journey but I can truly say, I’ve come along way!

Rather than saying which of these tenses is right or wrong, I will go through the sentence and say what meaning I understood from the writer's tense choices. In some cases I will suggest alternatives; not to correct anything, but to show that there are real choices here, they are all valid, and they all depend on what you actually want to say.

It has truly been a journey of self acceptance. (The perfect tense here describes the whole period from the beginning to this moment. We could say it was a journey (simple past tense), and that would emphasise more clearly that the journey towards self-acceptance is now complete.)

If there has ever been anyone... (same use of the perfect. We could use simple past ("if there ever was anyone") and it would mean basically the same thing.)

who was their own, worst critic... (The past tense here suggests self-reflection. I'm looking back on the journey to date, and during that time I was my own worst critic. I could use a present tense, and that might imply I'm still the same harsh self critc as in the past.)

it’s me. (Because this self-reflection is happening now.)

It’s an ongoing journey but I can truly say... (Again, present tenses for the present moment.)

I’ve come a long way! (On the whole journey from then till now.)


So in summary, the sentence as written is fine, but other options would also be fine, and you will choose the one that best communicates your message.

This is truly a great answer! Thanks a lot! Nonetheless, if you could spare a few more moments and explain to me why the writer of the second OP's example, in your opinion, said: "If there has ever been a man who has been faced with challenges... then it is King David.", if we know when King David lived? This example comes from the South African sorce, if that matters, but isn’t the only one I've found so far of the kind. What does it tell you? What is the meaning?

There are two perspectives in that sentence. There is King David, and there is the writer of the sentence. Is and was are both valid tenses here. The past tense means we are thinking from David's perspective. The present tense means we are thinking from the writer's perspective. Compare Looking back, Mother Teresa was the most inspirational figure of the 20th century, and To me, Mother Teresa is the most inspirational figure of the 20th century.

Yes, but why the writer used the Present Perfect: "If there has ever been a man who has been faced with challenges..." instead of the Past Simple: "If there has ever been a man who was faced with challenges...", if the character they were describing was dead? If King David were alive, then OK, but this way it sounds wrong! What do you think?

Ah, sorry. I saw the highlighted is, but missed the other one! Again, it's just perspective (I think). Was is certainly correct, and perhaps looks back from the writer's position: He [David] was faced... But if we put ourselves in the place of David, we can imagine him saying, "I have been faced with many challenges..." Has been brings out that flavour, and also makes the tenses consistent. We could also push the tense further back: A man who had been faced...

In conclusion, I'd like to ask one more thing! 1) "If there has ever been a great writer, who has written some of the greatest novels in the world, it is Charles Dickens." 2) "If there has ever been a soldier in the history of the U.S. Army, who has fought for his country until his last breath, it is general Robert E. Lee." Even if my characters are dead, I can still say this and bring out their actions closer to the present, make them more vivid so to say, as if they were alive? Am I correct?

These are just more examples of the same issue, which I've already answered. I don't mind you asking, but you are the one who will be writing in future. You are the one who must decide if your words say what you want them to say. For example, you could say: I think Charles Dickens is a fantastic writer, and he has written some of the greatest novels in the world. If you're not sure, rewrite. Your choice.

Of course, I understand! So, it wouldn't be a strange thing for you as a native English speaker if someone wrote that sentence, even though Charles Dickens is long dead and the narrative is in the present? Please, tell me, what does it tell you? What flavor brings the sentence written above to us in contrast with: I think Charles Dickens was a fantastic writer, and he wrote some of the greatest novels in the world.? May I ask you to help me with this?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Excuse me, @Peter, are you willing to continue this discussion in chat or not?

If you want to, yes, and that's why I set it up. All you need to do is click on the link.

I sent you a message, a day ago! Check it out. If I did something wrong, please let me know!

There is one more question left for you in chat, sir. If I may ask you to answer it and that way end the discussion. Thanks!

I believe that it is solely based on opinion.  The reason why they don't specify "then it was" is because of context.  The initial part of the statement is as if to address a specific, long-standing category requiring the listing or verbalization of who fits that scenario best.
The categorical statement is saying, based off of everything from the past, the present answer is [this].  Out of any past possibilities up to a certain point for being the worst critic, it would be one's self.  Since it is stated in first person, that person truly believes that currently, they are and have always been their own worst critic.  Out of all of the possibilities in the current past for someone to have faced challenges both at home and outside of it, the person believes the current, present answer to that question is King David.
Keep in mind that not all English speakers, past and present, follow current English ruling on sentence structure and that English changes with time.  What is deemed proper now, may not have been in the past.
